# Ruby array sorting order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, activerecord

I have this array returned by a activerecord query:

```
SELECT id, value FROM table ORDER BY value DESC
[1054, 86], [1062, 86], [1059, 84]
```

And I've created a simple array to compare with the first array:

array.sort_by! { |object| object.access_count }.reverse }

But when I compare the two arrays the result is different:

```
activerecord => [1054, 86], [1062, 86], [1059, 84]
array.sort_by! => [[1062, 86], [1054, 86], [1059, 84]
```

So in some cases the compare doesn't work because activerecord sorts one way and sort_by! sorts another.

How can I solve that ?
Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve by comparing both? can you explain a bit more? @gui12344455

Comment: yes, I'm using rspec to test my code and one test is to verify if the data returned is sorted correctly.

Comment: So you are trying test `order` method of Active record. Actually in RSpec we are responsible to test the code written by us. You no need to test order here. In case you are necessary to write test case for order, In the spec you can make a query like `records = Model.only(:id, :name).order(:desc)` and check like this `expected(response_records).to eq(records)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try order Activerecord with second arg.

```
.order(value: :desc, id: :desc)
```